# HTTP request 408 error(Client request timeout) over mobile network. Django + Gunicorn + Nginx

Tags: django, http, nginx, gunicorn

I have faced with strange issue. My API has endpoint on which i am using PATCH(tried also PUT and POST - same result) to send json with jsonarray(request body size typically is 40KB) from mobile phone. When i am doing this using Wi-Fi - all works fine. But if i am using mobile network, i am facing with SocketConnection Timeout(in Retrofit/Kotlin) with some phones(iOS works perfect).

From nginx access.log :

```
domain - - [21/Nov/2017:16:33:01 +0000] "PATCH /endpoint/ HTTP/1.1" 408 0 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/M4B30Z)"
```

Nginx config :

```
server {
    listen port;
    server_name domain;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
      root /home/user/apps/api;
    }


     location / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/apps/api/api.sock;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

Gunicorn config :

```
respawn
setuid root
setgid www-data
chdir /home/user/apps/api

exec /home/user/virtualenvs/apienv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout=90 --bind unix://api.sock api.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in network connection. We changed location of our clouds from Frankfurt to Amsterdam and now all works perfect